# How to fix connection refused and can't find a master error on elasticsearch mongoriver

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I'm experiencing this error when starting elasticsearch

```
~  elasticsearch -f
getopt: illegal option -- f
[2014-04-22 23:23:27,793][INFO ][node                     ] [Starlight] version[1.0.0], pid[3785], build[a46900e/2014-02-12T16:18:34Z]
[2014-04-22 23:23:27,794][INFO ][node                     ] [Starlight] initializing ...
[2014-04-22 23:23:27,837][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Starlight] loaded [mongodb-river, mapper-attachments], sites [river-mongodb]
[2014-04-22 23:23:29,997][INFO ][node                     ] [Starlight] initialized
[2014-04-22 23:23:29,998][INFO ][node                     ] [Starlight] starting ...
[2014-04-22 23:23:30,077][INFO ][transport                ] [Starlight] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]}
[2014-04-22 23:23:33,149][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Starlight] new_master [Starlight][5kL_aPXDQVy-kecgDGY4VA][JOHNs-MacBook-Pro.local][inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2014-04-22 23:23:33,177][INFO ][discovery                ] [Starlight] elasticsearch_johnkevinmbasco/5kL_aPXDQVy-kecgDGY4VA
[2014-04-22 23:23:33,200][INFO ][http                     ] [Starlight] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9200]}
[2014-04-22 23:23:33,880][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Starlight] recovered [11] indices into cluster_state
[2014-04-22 23:23:34,990][INFO ][river.mongodb            ] Parse river settings for mongodb
[2014-04-22 23:23:34,993][INFO ][river.mongodb            ] Server: 127.0.0.1 - 27017
[2014-04-22 23:23:35,020][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Starting river mongodb
[2014-04-22 23:23:35,031][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] MongoDB River Plugin - version[2.0.0] - hash[a0c23f1] - time[2014-02-23T20:40:05Z]
[2014-04-22 23:23:35,032][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] starting mongodb stream. options: secondaryreadpreference [false], drop_collection [false], include_collection [], throttlesize [5000], gridfs [false], filter [null], db [testmongo], collection [person], script [null], indexing to [mongoindex]/[person]
Apr 22, 2014 11:23:35 PM com.mongodb.ConnectionStatus$UpdatableNode update
WARNING: Server seen down: JOHNs-MacBook-Pro.local/10.209.30.254:27017
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:382)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:228)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:431)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:223)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:125)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:106)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:162)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.runCommand(DBPort.java:170)
    at com.mongodb.ConnectionStatus$UpdatableNode.update(ConnectionStatus.java:196)
    at com.mongodb.ReplicaSetStatus$UpdatableReplicaSetNode.update(ReplicaSetStatus.java:603)
    at com.mongodb.ReplicaSetStatus$Updater.updateAll(ReplicaSetStatus.java:755)
    at com.mongodb.ReplicaSetStatus$Updater.run(ReplicaSetStatus.java:725)
[2014-04-22 23:23:35,367][INFO ][node                     ] [Starlight] started
[2014-04-22 23:23:35,397][WARN ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Fail to start river mongodb
com.mongodb.MongoException: can't find a master
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.checkMaster(DBTCPConnector.java:517)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:236)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:216)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:288)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:262)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:244)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:301)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:199)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver.isMongos(MongoDBRiver.java:264)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver.start(MongoDBRiver.java:208)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.RiversService.createRiver(RiversService.java:148)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.RiversService$ApplyRivers$2.onResponse(RiversService.java:275)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.RiversService$ApplyRivers$2.onResponse(RiversService.java:269)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$ThreadedActionListener$1.run(TransportAction.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
[2014-04-22 23:23:38,979][WARN ][river.routing            ] [Starlight] no river _meta document found after 5 attempts
[2014-04-22 23:23:39,083][WARN ][river.routing            ] [Starlight] no river _meta document found after 5 attempts
[2014-04-22 23:23:39,204][WARN ][river.routing            ] [Starlight] no river _meta document found after 5 attempts
[2014-04-22 23:23:39,287][WARN ][river.routing            ] [Starlight] no river _meta document found after 5 attempts
[2014-04-22 23:23:39,345][WARN ][river.routing            ] [Starlight] no river _meta document found after 5 attempts
[2014-04-22 23:23:39,356][WARN ][river.routing            ] [Starlight] no river _meta document found after 5 attempts
[2014-04-22 23:23:39,371][WARN ][river.routing            ] [Starlight] no river _meta document found after 5 attempts
[2014-04-22 23:23:39,374][WARN ][river.routing            ] [Starlight] no river _meta document found after 5 attempts
```

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

And here is the output of rs.status()

```
{
    "set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-22T15:26:33Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "JOHNs-MacBook-Pro.local:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 503,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1398179531, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-04-22T15:12:11Z"),
            "self" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

ifconfig output:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8823<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 54:26:96:d8:3e:57
    media: autoselect (<unknown type>)
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8802<BROADCAST,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 06:26:96:d8:3e:57
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
ppp0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 10.141.75.33 --> 10.64.64.64 netmask 0xff000000
```

I'm using MongoDB River Plugin 2.0.0 - https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb, Elasticsearch 1.0.0 and MongoDB 2.4.9

Comment: What does the name "JOHNs-MacBook-Pro.local" resolves to? 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @yaoxing - Not sure. But I'm running mongo and elasticsearch on the same machine so I guess "JOHNs-MacBook-Pro.local" resolves to "127.0.0.1". Correct?

Comment: So that's the issue I'm talking about in my answer. have a look.

Comment: Can you run the command: ping JOHNs-MacBook-Pro.local to make sure?

Comment: @yaoxing - here's the output: PING johns-macbook-pro.local (192.168.192.101): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.192.101: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.192.101: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.127 ms

Comment: Hmm, I didn't see the IP 192.168.192.101 in your IP addresses

Comment: @yaoxing - I run ifconfig again today. It's present in my IP addresses - en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
 ether 54:26:96:d8:3e:57
 inet6 fe80::5626:96ff:fed8:3e57%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4
 inet 192.168.192.101 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.192.255
 media: autoselect
 status: active

Comment: @yaoxing - Anyway I posted a comment on your answer below. Can you kindly check it please. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51222/discussion-between-yaoxing-and-john-kevin-m-basco)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that what you write in the connection string is not what the driver's going to connect to. For replica set, the URL, for exampl:

```
mongodb://hostname/some_db
```

Here the hostname is a "seed" where your driver's going to get a "available server list". This is because a replica set is usually variable. You can add or remove a node to/from a replica set any time. Thus the available list is always got from the seed.
Here from your information, it returns a one-member list:

```
"name" : "JOHNs-MacBook-Pro.local:27017",
```

So the driver later tries to connect to JOHNs-MacBook-Pro.local:27017. What you need to make sure is that the name JOHNs-MacBook-Pro.local:27017 should be accessible from your client machine. So if it resolves to 127.0.0.1, your client will never be able to connect to it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm running mongo and elasticsearch on the same machine. Can you please explain why my client will never be able to connect to it if JOHNs-MacBook-Pro.local:27017 resolves to 127.0.0.1? Anyway, I modified the host in my rs.config() from JOHNs-MacBook-Pro.local:27017 to localhost:27017 and it works now. Is this the correct solution?

Comment: it's not a good way. it'll work for you. But if someone else tries to connect to your machine, it's not going to work. Because localhost always resolves to 127.0.0.1 which is his own machine.